# Extract cab file and use the database

Tags: database, sqlite, windows-mobile, cab

I found an old windows mobile dictionary application and I want to get the database. I extract it but I don't know how to convert it to csv or sql file. Have anybody idea about it ?

You can download the file from here http://www.mediafire.com/download/z32xgmc9fia3nr2/OGD.Akilli.Sozluk.CAB

And I use Ubuntu.

Comment: What type of database is it?  You may be able to tell by the file extension, or open the file in a hex editor and look at the first few bytes to see if you can spot a header.

Comment: @TrevorBalcom I tried to open in terminal and it is Sqlite file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite makes available the C source code to compile a shell program which can be used to do this.  It's apparently also included by Ubuntu.  Here is the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/sqlite3.1.html) for the sqlite shell included with Ubuntu. Please review the documentation as there are a few ways to convert to CSV or get the schema of a table.

Alternatively, you can use a 3rd party tool to view the database in a GUI.  I can't speak for Linux solutions, but Firefox has a 3rd party plugin called ["SQLite Manager"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) that will let you use SQLite files in a GUI if you prefer it that way.